# Copy environment properties into WAR with Gradle and dynamically update a version property

Tags: gradle, war

I have a gradle build that creates multiple war files, one for each environment defined in a config directory. For example, the directory structure as follows would produce 3 wars:

```
cfg
- dev
   - application.properties
   - log4j.properties
- staging
   - application.properties
   - log4j.properties
- production
   - application.properties
   - log4j.properties
```

The application's version is in the gradle file and also in the `application.properties` files under the key `app.version`. I would like to maintain the version only in `build.gradle` and have the value copied into application.properties files on build.

The piece of my gradle script that creates and executes the builds is below. I've tried a few approaches including the `ant.replace` task to copy over the version (included in the script) but I can't seem to find the right file reference to the application.properties file to get this to work. I am also happy to accept any other approaches to building the wars.

```
// generate package* tasks for all defined configurations
files { file('cfg').listFiles() }.each { 
    File file -> if (file.name != 'common' && file.name != '.svn') {
        tasks.create(name: "package$file.name", type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
            classifier = file.name
            from("./cfg/$file.name") {
                into("WEB-INF/classes")
                include "**/*"
            }
            ant.replace(file:"WEB-INF/classes/application.properties", token:"@appVersion", value:project.version)
        }
    }
}

// run all assemble tasks
task dist (dependsOn: tasks.matching { Task task -> task.name.startsWith("package") })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be simplified a bit:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

project.file('cfg').listFiles().each { File file ->
   if (file.name != 'common' && file.name != '.svn') {
      tasks.create(name: "package$file.name", type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
         classifier = file.name
         from(file) {
            into('WEB-INF/classes')
            include "**/*"            
            filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['app.version': '2.3.1'])
         }
      }
   }
}

task dist (dependsOn: tasks.matching { Task task -> task.name.startsWith("package") })
```

Full demo [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/29246356), have a look at the [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) as well.

Comment: Follow up question: how do I dynamically reference the war's build `version` property in place of `'2.3.1'`?

Comment: I should clarify that when this is in the same file as the version declaration it works correctly, however I am attempting to define the above in an external file that is included by a local build file that just defines dependencies and version.

Comment: @Luke, have just updated the answer on github, please have a look at it. You can pass it via system property e.g.

Comment: Thanks Opal. I had managed to get it to work as you've done it, having all functions on a single build file. I was attempting to have common build function in a separate file, then have the project's dependencies, version, group etc in a project build file (which imports the common). The version always comes up unspecified when I do it this way, so I've just gone with a single build file. Thanks for your help!